# Condition for a product of two function sequences in $L^1$ to be in $L^1$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, lp-spaces

We have: 
 
 1. $\{f_n\} \subset L^1(E, \Sigma, \mu)$ 
 2. $g_n \subset L^\infty(E, \Sigma, \mu)$ 
 3. $\|f_n-f\|_{L^1}\to0$ 
 4. $g_n \to g \text{ }\mu\text{-a.e.}$ 
 5. $\{g_n\}$ is uniformly bounded.

 Then show that $\|f_n g_n- f g\|_{L^1} \to 0$

I've been trying to apply the usual trick of

$$|f_n g_n-fg|=|f_n g_n-g_nf+g_nf-fg|\leq|g_n||f_n-f|+|f||g_n-g|$$

and then integrating. Under the assumptions all the terms (and factors) except $|g_n-g|$ either go to zero in the norm (or the factors are bounded). The problem with $|g_n-g|$ is that to make the $L^1$ norm go to zero I need to assume that $\mu(E)<\infty$ to apply the Dominated Convergence Theorem, adding one more assumption. Is there any other way without assuming this.

Comment: You can choose a set $F$ of finite measure such that $\int_{F^C} |f|$ is small. Then write $\int_E |f||g_n-g|=\int_F |f||g_n-g|+\int_{F^C} |f||g_n-g|$. The former integral can be made small using the $L_1$-convergence of $g_n$ to $g$ on $F$ and the latter is small since $(g_n-g)$ is uniformly bounded.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what allows one to choose such an $F$. Assuming $\mu(E)=\infty$, we must have $\mu(F^C)=\infty$. How will $\int |f|$ be small on this set?

Comment: Let $f_n=f\cdot\chi_{[-n,n]}$. By the Dominated Convergence Theorem $f_n\rightarrow f$ in $L_1$. The result follows from this.